# Sencha (v5) App Watch not picking up SASS changes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, extjs, sass, touch

I run,

```
Sencha App Watch
```

Inside my Sencha Touch 2 app. Which should from the sencha docs compile the sass for me. My sass file is in resources/sass/app.scss, where sencha put it. Though its not picking up my scss changes that I make. While running the app watch, all i see is:

```
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
[INF] Updating CompileWatcher file system registrations...
[INF] Waiting for changes...
```

I also have my config.rb file in that directory

```
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework automatically.
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', '../touch', 'resources', 'themes')

# Compass configurations
sass_path = dir
css_path = File.join(dir, "..", "css")

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
images_dir = File.join(dir, "..", "images")
output_style = :compressed
environment = :production
```

I'm using the most recent version of Sencha CMD v5 (v5.0.0.160). Could it be a bug with sencha v5? What am I missing here? 
Thanks folks!!

Answer (score 0):

With me being fairly new to sencha/and sass framework I didn't know why my css changes we're not taking.

I was trying to do some overrides to the $base-color sass variable in my app.scss:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
$base-color: #42282E;
```

I assumed that sass variables cascaded, like normal property overrides. Well I was certainly wrong. After thinking about it for a couple mins, I realized since this was a variable Sass must be parsing it before it gets to my $base-color variable. So i just threw my variable above the @imports and vola.

```
$base-color: #42282E;
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
```

**lesson learned: Sass variables need to be set before the sencha imports.**

It's frustrating to me that it has to be implemented like this. Maybe its because its just the way @imports are supposed be handled, but it would be super handy if it would wait until it scanned all the files for variables before replacing the variables.

With all that said, I'm glad to finally know how to get the sass overrides to work. Hope this helps someone else.